# Putting question on hold rather than downvoting?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I asked a question on Stack Overflow. I got three downvotes and one upvote. I deleted the question and got +3 for peer pressure. At the end +8-8=0.

I can understand why the question was downvoted. But I find the explanation

```
too much code [...] TL;DR
```

very confusing. Because I feel that the problem cannot be shown with less code. I even posted a fiddle. I removed the code, simplified my question and only left the link to the fiddle. But with a -3 no one came back to read the question.

***Isn't there something paradoxical in a TL;DR downvote, as the guy himself admittedly downvoted a post he did not read?***

***Maybe, put on hold badge should be easier and downvoting question costs more? And the question date could be updated when the hold is off?***

It would prevent people from rewriting their questions for nothing...

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536108/width-of-fixed-element-in-bootstrap-grids-in-pure-css*

Comment: Just a guess since I do not have the rep to see that post, based soley on the comment: Perhaps they thought it was a code dump? Did you put adequate explanation of your problem in the post? Did you post only the minimum code needed to reproduce the problem at hand?

Comment: A downvote means "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Take away from that what you want. Questions can be closed because they are unclear, or they can be closed for other reasons (e.g. off-topic). Closing is not the same as downvoting.

Comment: Tangential: You don't get +3 reputation for "Peer Pressure". That's a badge. Your +3 was the undoing of the votes ((1x10) - (4x2))= 2, but you had only lost 7, not 8, for the down votes (since you were at 1 already), so you got +3.

Comment: I don't think you posted too much code. The CSS part may be a little long, but may also be necessary to understand your problem. Otherwise you posted 20 lines of markup and 6 lines of code, which is perfectly acceptable. If people are too lazy to read that, they should arguably go watch some TV rather than downvote or vote to close.

Comment: @Kendra I had posted 2 other close stack overflow answers. Explained the problem, then wrote the HTML & CSS code minus the content and djangocms placeholders.

Comment: @Sumurai8 There where research effort, as explained to Kendra. I do not mean closing the question, but only "put on hold" for as long as an experienced user believes the question is not clear enough.

Comment: @user2346536 Fair enough- Just a few suggestions since I can't see the question in question.

Comment: @AndrewBarber thanks I did not know.

Comment: @user2346536 I can't see deleted questions. I just point out the difference between downvotes and close votes. Besides that, people are more or less free to vote as they please. Somehow the votes still more or less represent the quality of a question. (btw: close votes are those things that put a question on hold. After 2 weeks of being on hold it will change to [closed], but it is essentially the same)

Comment: @Sumurai8 It's 5 days, not 2 weeks.

Comment: Don't just dump code in your question.  ***Always*** pear your actual code down to the *smallest number of lines that reproduces your issue*.  It is an important courtesy to those who are helping you for free.  Nobody wants to wade through five hundred lines of worthless code to find the two lines where your issue lies.  Also, the use of fiddles for reproducing your issue (soon to be embedded in SO!) helps answerers see and work on your problems.  Makes it very easy and convenient to help you.

Comment: @Sumurai8 thanks, I did not know, I should read more of SO rules maybe...

Comment: @Will I totally agree, my actual code was few hundreds lines, the one I showed, was 20, and I believe minimal given the problem. By courtesy, I provided a fiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Users are not given a choice between *either* downvoting *or* closing.  They can do one, the other, both, or neither.  That someone is closing a question doesn't mean that they can't downvote; that they're downvoting doesn't mean that they can't vote to close.

As for the user's comment you mention, it's important when posting an SO question to limit the scope of the code that you post.  You need to do your best to come up with a minimal reproduction of the problem with the shortest and simplest code that you are able to.  Readers are not expected to take a large block of code and attempt to divine what is and is not relevant to your problem for you; you should be doing that before you post your question (at least to the best of your abilities).

Just removing all of the code and posting a link is no better.  In fact, it's worse.  What you need to do is actually spend some time debugging your program to figure out what code you can remove and still reproduce the issue.  The downvotes are (according to that comment) reflecting the fact that you have not put that debugging effort in.

Comment: This is not true. as  Frédéric Hamidi said 20 lines of markup and 6 lines of CSS is definitely not much. and the debugging effort were made. I had a solution based on Jquery, but I believed this could be done straight in CSS, I just could not find how. And I posted two close answers from SO.

Comment: I mean, down-voting question has no cost, and so is too easy. It would be more constructive to lower the level of a "put on hold" badge. But down-voting should not be free.

Comment: reading around free down votes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free

Comment: @user2346536 It's not just a function of how much code there is, but how much of the code is relevant to the problem at hand.  If 70% of the code that you had can be removed without affecting the question, leaving just the 30% that's actually relevant to the problem, that's a *radical* improvement in question clarity.  That's what that comment was saying.

Comment: @user2346536 Downvotes are very important.  They're one of the most important features of the site; the ability for the community to express its feedback on the quality of content and make that feedback visible to others.  Adding a lot of resistance to providing that feedback means that people won't do it, and that's very harmful, not helpful.  Sure, it doesn't feel good to get negative feedback, most people (unfortunately) don't enjoy it, even when it's constructive.  You'd be far less happy if you constantly kept finding posts that had positive feedback but were full of major problem.

Comment: @Servy At least one person up-voted the post. Read the code, I would have difficulty to have my described use-case with fewer lines!

Comment: @user2346536 Well apparently several other people disagree with that assertion.

Comment: @Servy I understand, I have posted crappy questions in the past and get downvoted for them. It is not pleasant, but I accept it. However, this question did not deserve these down votes, and they prevented me from getting an answer! I have a life out of SO, downvote me 100 times I'll still sleep very well, but here, I just would not get my answer because people abuse downvote because they like this little power... This is how I felt, but surely it is subjective. :)

Comment: @user2346536 They told you exactly why they downvoted, and it had nothing to do with doing it just to feel powerful.  They felt you didn't do an adequate job in constructing your example code succinctly.  That said, they didn't prevent you from getting an answer.  You were the only one to do that by deleting your question.  They merely informed you that your question needed improvement and told you how your question could be improved.  You were the one who deleted the question, preventing answers.

Comment: @Servy a down-voted question, can remain for years on SO without anyone reading it, but fair enough, I accepted your answer.

Comment: @user2346536 Sure it can, or it could be improved by the author based on the feedback given and answered.  You were asked to fix your question and rather than fix your question you choose to delete it.  That was *your* choice.  If getting an answer to your question is important enough then you should take the time to improve the question based on the feedback you've been given.

Comment: @Servy This is what I thought I did, leaving only the explanation and the fiddle. I deleted the question only to undelete it later after modification and if I really could not find a way out alone. during this time I do not keep getting downvotes and people don't read the old version. I edited the question, told the guy by comment and he did not answer... this is what happened !